# Youtube player fragment is not working when activity goes in background and come back in forground

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

I'm creating app for tablet screen so my video list and youtube player both are in same activity. [image] When first time app is start every thing work great.

But when i click back button and then start again app so if I am not manage state when activity come bake in to foreground at that time fragment is not showing it's just show white screen and when I click in any video from list it's throw NullPointException.[image]

If I manage state than it's throw IllegalStateException.[image]

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(Singleton.getInstance().getVideoUrl().length()!=0) {
        VideoUrl = utils.getYouTubeVideoId(Singleton.getInstance().getKidsDataGetterSetter().get(Singleton.getInstance().getPosition()).getVideo_url());
        YPlayer = Singleton.getInstance().getYPlayer();
        youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubePlayerFragment.getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(KidsConstantClass.API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
        YPlayer.loadVideo(VideoUrl); <=(Line 313)
    }
}
```

If any one know please help me!
Thank you

Comment: added homeActivity.java code, at-lest 313 line number

Comment: have you used two fragment in single activity?? for above layout?? why you have added fragment in onResume?? i need to check you full activity code as well layout to resolve your query.

Comment: @Dhawal I solved problem by the way thanks for help.

Comment: Could you post your answer please? That would be helpful, thank's.

Comment: @Shargotth Sorry for the late reply, Do you still need the answer?

Comment: i have the same problem, you found any solution for this?. If so, please add the answer, I would appreciate